# UIImageView load from file path stored in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I've created my own custom Table View Cell comprising of a number, an image (thumbnail) and a description of something that is successfully being stored in a sqlite database using Core Data.

The image below will give a better idea of what I currently have in Interface Builder:
[image]

In the screen before, I am storing the filepath of an image taken with the camera and saving it to the database. I want to be able to load each UIImageView on the Table View Cells with the filepaths stored against each item.

I have tried the following which does not work:

```
UIImageView * thingPhotoView = (UIImageView *)
    [cell viewWithTag:11];

    NSString *path = thing.photo;
    thingPhotoView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: Can you ensure that `thingPhotoView`, `path` and `thing` are all not `nil`. Then can you tell us what the value of `path` is.

Comment: They are all not nil, and  value of path is assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=B234919E-4D6F-4042-9731-D86EC0869550&ext=JPG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used `ALAssetLibrary` but judging by the URL that is what you are using. Therefore you will need to use `ALAssetsLibrary` to access the file

Check the docs here [ALAssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You probably want this method

```
assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:
```

Which might look like this

```
ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library assetForURL:thing.photo
     resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

         thingPhotoView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]];

     } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {

       NSLog(@"Couldn't load asset %@ => %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);

     }];
```

Comment: Brilliant, works like a charm. I had to convert the NSURL into an NSString to store it, but just converted it back again when the image is displayed, using NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:thing.photo];